# Integrate Speech to Text bot framework for teams channel?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams

We are working on a chatbot with botframework, the bot is deployed to the teams channel, but we need to integrate Speech to text service of microsoft into this teams channel for the bot ,is that possible?

I could see speech-text requires a different directline channel all together in the documention but nothing of having it in teams Bot App.

Anyone know of this being possible?

Comment: Currently this is not possible.

Comment: As stated above, this is not supported as of now. Refer to https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/555103-public/suggestions/33534778-speech-to-text-meeting-notes?page=2&per_page=20 and https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/7a135202-5410-4960-80aa-8239ad38a24b/how-to-enable-speech-to-text-through-microsoft-teams?forum=msteams

Comment: Thanks VaraPrasad..is it only possible for web application at the moment then?

Comment: @sree, Currently this is not supported in teams in both desktop and web.

Answer (score 1):

Currently this is not supported in teams in both desktop and web.